# Responsive images with css/html

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm making a website and I'm trying to make it responsive. The first thing that I want to make responsive is the header. On the header I have the logo of the website and 5 buttons that are "Home", "About", "Team" and "Contact Us"

The HTML looks like this:

```
    <div class="clearfix" id="header" style="">            

        <div class="clearfix" id="logo" style="">
            <!-- Lynxus Logo -->
            <a class="nonblock nontext museBGSize grpelem" id="u223" href="index.html"><!-- simple frame --></a>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix" id="nav" style="">
            <!-- Home -->
            <a class="nonblock nontext museBGSize grpelem" id="u224" href="index.html"><!-- simple frame --></a>
            <!-- About -->
            <a class="nonblock nontext museBGSize grpelem" id="u225" href="#"><!-- simple frame --></a>
            <!-- Team -->
            <a class="nonblock nontext museBGSize grpelem" id="u226" href="#"><!-- simple frame --></a>
            <!-- Blog -->
            <a class="nonblock nontext museBGSize grpelem" id="u227" href="http://lynxusapp.blogspot.com/" target="_blank"><!-- simple frame --></a>
            <!-- Contact Us -->
            <a class="nonblock nontext museBGSize grpelem" id="u228" href="#"><!-- simple frame --></a>
        </div>
```

and the css is like this:

```
#header
{
z-index: 1;
width: 100%;
min-height: 80px;        
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left:0;
right:0;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#logo{
z-index: 1;
width: 228px;
min-height: 80px;        
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left:0;
right:0;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#nav{
z-index: 1;
width: 732px;
min-height: 80px;        
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left:0;
right:0;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;    
}

#u223
{
z-index: 16;
width: 228px;
height: 77px;
position: relative;
margin-right: -10000px;
margin-top: 10px;
left: 10px;
background: transparent url("../images/LynxusLogo.png") no-repeat left top;
background-size: contain !important;
}

#u224
{
z-index: 17;
width: 131px;
height: 33px;
position: relative;
margin-right: -10000px;
margin-top: 30px;
left: 280px;
background: transparent url("../images/Home.png") no-repeat left top;
background-size: contain !important;
}

#u224:hover
{
margin: 30px -10000px 0px 0px;
background: transparent url("../images/Home-hover.png") no-repeat left top;
background-size: contain !important;
}

#u225
{
z-index: 18;
width: 131px;
height: 33px;
position: relative;
margin-right: -10000px;
margin-top: 30px;
left: 430px;
background: transparent url("../images/About.png") no-repeat left top;
background-size: contain !important;
}

#u225:hover
{
margin: 30px -10000px 0px 0px;
background: transparent url("../images/About-hover.png") no-repeat left top;
background-size: contain !important;
}

#u226
{
z-index: 19;
width: 131px;
height: 33px;
position: relative;
margin-right: -10000px;
margin-top: 30px;
left: 580px;
background: transparent url("../images/Team.png") no-repeat left top;
background-size: contain !important;
}

#u226:hover
{
margin: 30px -10000px 0px 0px;
background: transparent url("../images/Team-hover.png") no-repeat left top;
background-size: contain !important;
}

#u227
{
z-index: 20;
width: 131px;
height: 33px;
position: relative;
margin-right: -10000px;
margin-top: 30px;
left: 730px;
background: transparent url("../images/Blog.png") no-repeat left top;
background-size: contain !important;
}

#u227:hover
{
margin: 30px -10000px 0px 0px;
background: transparent url("../images/Blog-hover.png") no-repeat left top;
background-size: contain !important;
}

#u228
{
z-index: 21;
width: 131px;
height: 33px;
position: relative;
margin-right: -10000px;
margin-top: 30px;
left: 880px;
background: transparent url("../images/Contact.png") no-repeat left top;
background-size: contain !important;
}

#u228:hover
{
margin: 30px -10000px 0px 0px;
background: transparent url("../images/Contact-hover.png") no-repeat left top;
background-size: contain !important;
}
```

I've been trying to use min-height, min-width and other stuff that I've found on the Internet but they haven't worked so far. Does anyone know how I can solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by make responsive?

Comment: By responsive do you mean you want the different sections of the header to scale as the window resizes?

Comment: I mean when I make the window small the buttons should re-size to fit on it

Answer (score 0):

Responsive designs responds to media queries in CSS3. It Detects the width of the device/browser and responds accordingly

```
    /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-width : 321px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (max-width : 320px) {
    /* Styles */
    }        

    /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) {        
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
    and (orientation : landscape) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
    and (orientation : portrait) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-width : 1224px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Large screens ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-width : 1824px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* iPhone 4 ----------- */
    @media
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
    /* Styles */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give both the parent container and the image max-width and height:auto.

```
#header {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#logo {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a scheme like this.  Check it out my example.  You can expand and shrink down the display panel to see how it is responsive. [**Take a look at this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/asapmmeehan/jULhV/8/)

If you like it maybe I could expand on this a bit.

```
#header {
    width:90%;
    float:left;
    background:#999;
    padding:20px 5%;
}

#logo {
    width:40%;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    margin:0 10% 0 0;
    background:#666;
}

#nav {
    width:50%;
    float:left;

}

#nav .nav-item {
    width:14%;
    float:left;
    margin:0 1%;
    padding:10px 2%;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying this method and It's kind of working. However the nav items are staying to much on the right

Comment: Change the #nav float from left to right.  If you look at what I have above you can see that the width of the #logo and the #nav (including margin = 100%;).