# How can I do my background image responsive

Tags: css, html, responsive

I am working on my webpage. I am facing couple of problems at the moment:

Images do not adapt to the size of the browser window, if I make the browser window smaller image will be shown as repeated

I want, that each picture take the whole display

How can I do that footer and menu stay visible during the scrolling?

Here is the link to [Codepen](http://codepen.io/kryvosheya/pen/xVrPej)

```
#intro{
  background-image: url("http://www.tricentis.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/photo-1435575653489-b0873ec954e2.jpg");
  padding-top: 30px;
  background-size: cover; 
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: The reason you see the background image double up is because you have the `background-size: 100%` property set. This overrides the `background-size: cover` property which is the one you actually want. Remove the `background-size: 100%` and you should be good to go. If you want the footer and header to stay at a fixed position, try setting them to `position: fixed`.

Comment: It is a good practice to mention, what you have tried previously. The question is a bit broad and there are similar questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394168/responsive-images-with-css-html), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762957/responsive-images) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233558/how-to-set-responsively-images-on-images-to-appear-fixed-using-htmlcssjs).

Answer (score 0):

doesn't do any good to set background size to `cover` if you're going to set it to `100%` a couple lines down. remove `background-size:100%` and it works fine.

Comment: thanks. I did it, but the problem is in small display, in this case I have white space between the pictures

Comment: you may try contain instead of cover.

Answer (score -1):

You can set

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

to make sure each image isn't shown more than once.